# How to concatenate values of each sub-folders (children) to their parent folders respectively

Tags: bash, shell, find, cat

I have directory tree root that looks like this

> /sys/class/gpio/chip**/$$

** represent  as **8** parent folders, **$$** represent as **16** children sub-folders. each child contains extension-less file that has a ASCII value of only **0** or **1**.
How can I concatenate the values of each sub-folders (16 children) in their parent folders (8) respectively, so that in each parent folder there will be a output file that should contains 16 ASCII values of 0 or 1 (merge of the 16 children).
I've managed to perform concatenation in each sub-folder, hence the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in */; do
find -name "" -execdir sh -c 'cat {} >> out' \;
done
```

> In **normal** condition state, all of the 16 children should be 0 or 1
>   **unanimously**, but I need to validate this **each time**.

In the current state I get `out` file in each sub-folder and I can't just move or copy this file to the parent folder and overwrite it, because I need to check also for a scenario **for example**, that two of the children value isn't identical to the other 14 child in their group (parent folder). **For example:** In parent folder #1: 14 children values are 1's and the other 2 children values are 0's. 
Can I overcome this during the `find` and `cat` stages, if not so how then?
- Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: if you know the exact path or depth you don't need `find`, and don't need to fork process for each file so can manage the redirection in current process

Comment: @Nahuel Fouilleul So how then I find all the specific files and concatenate them into one? - Can you demonstrate this by code please?

Comment: i can't because i didn't understand the question what do you want to do? can you give a clear example ?